# Check if event is firing with Facebook SDK

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, sdk

I'm working with Facebook SDK Javascript in the v2.10 on a React APP and i'm trying to check when a comment is created to send a POST request to send an email.

I'm using Facebook sdk provider and comments plugin of react-facebook

```
      <FacebookProvider appId="{FACEBOOK_APP_ID}">
        <Comments width="100%" class="comments" href="{FB_COMMENTS_BASE}{props.location.pathname}" />
      </FacebookProvider>
```

And i have an async init for FB SDK

```
window.fbAsyncInit = () => {
    FB.init({
        appId: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
        autoLogAppEvents: true,
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.10'
    })
    console.log('Async init');
    FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', (response) => {
      fetchComment(response)
    })
}
if (!document.querySelector('script[src*="connect.facebook.net"]'))
    loadScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js')
```

The 'async init' is printed in the console but the subscribe callback function is not firing when someone wrote a comment. So there's a way to know all of the event that are firing to check if is the real name?

PDI: the fetchComment function is only an console.log

PDII: i read about changing the name of the event to "comments.create" but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event `comment.create` is not mentioned any more in the documentation, , so I guess we can assume it was removed. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v3.2

The documentation for the Comments plugin mentions **Webhooks** as a method to get notified when new comments are posted for a URL: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#webhooks

Answer (score 1):

It is officially killed as they confirmed. Thanks misorude for pointing out that they move it to Webhook.

[https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/927463134113943/](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/927463134113943/#)